# Oracle :Get Value based on a pervious record based on period

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

LAG function is working when use in directly in the table.

```
SELECT pgm_id,
       pml.period_id,
       medi_cov_lives,
       LAG (medi_cov_lives, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY pml.pgm_id, pml.period_id)
          AS prior_medi_cov_lives
  FROM PGM_MEDI_LIVES pml
 WHERE pgm_id = 1548
```

output:

```
PGM_ID  PERIOD_ID   MEDI_COV_LIVES      PRIOR_MEDI_COV_LIVES
1548    125     1,099,842       0
1548    126     754,245         1,099,842
1548    127     712,422         754,245
1548    128     732,115         712,422
1548    129     1,119,876       732,115
1548    130     1,234,567       1,119,876
```

but i need join this  with other query so i have created view and passed the pgm_id=1548 then its showing the last value is wrong.

because it doing the LGA for whole table and then its showing the last value from other period. can u please help to get the right result

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW HCRS.PGM_MEDI_LIVES_V
(
   PGM_ID,
   PERIOD_ID,
   MEDI_COV_LIVES,
   PREV_MEDI_COV_LIVES
)
AS
   SELECT 
         pgm_id,
          pml.period_id,
          medi_cov_lives,
          LAG (medi_cov_lives, 1, 0)
             OVER (ORDER BY pml.pgm_id, pml.period_id)
             AS pre_medi_cov_lives
     FROM PGM_MEDI_LIVES pml;

select * from HCRS.PGM_MEDI_LIVES_V where pgm_id=1548
```

output

```
PGM_ID  PERIOD_ID   MEDI_COV_LIVES      PRIOR_MEDI_COV_LIVES
1548    125     1,099,842       100000          ---- its taking someother period value
1548    126     754,245         1,099,842
1548    127     712,422         754,245
1548    128     732,115         712,422
1548    129     1,119,876       732,115
1548    130     1,234,567       1,119,876
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `partition by`:

```
SELECT pgm_id, pml.period_id, medi_cov_lives,
       LAG(medi_cov_lives, 1, 0)
          OVER (PARTITION BY pgm_id ORDER BY pml.pgm_id, pml.period_id
               ) AS pre_medi_cov_lives
FROM <table> pml;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify to `lag` to handle each `pgm_id` separately, with a `partition by` clause:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW HCRS.PGM_MEDI_LIVES_V
(
   PGM_ID,
   PERIOD_ID,
   MEDI_COV_LIVES,
   PREV_MEDI_COV_LIVES
)
AS
   SELECT 
         pgm_id,
         pml.period_id,
         medi_cov_lives,
         LAG (medi_cov_lives, 1, 0)
             OVER (PARTITION BY pml.pgm_id ORDER BY pml.period_id)
             AS pre_medi_cov_lives
     FROM PGM_MEDI_LIVES pml;
```